# Get list of available audio devices on iOS/Android with Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, media

In my flutter application I want to switch between headphone to speaker vice versa.

I am looking for a way to get the available audio devices and to switch them.

I found;

```
final mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
var devices = await mediaDevices.getSources();
```

It is not clear to me what this navigator is?

May I know whether there is a way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator And subsequently https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mediaDevices

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Is seems this is a web based solution. Is there a solution on ios and android devices?

Comment: If it's browser based, then the above is still fine. Doing this for a native app, you'd need to interact with the native audio APIs.

Comment: Some work might potentially be done for  you with the [Flutter Sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) package. In particular you'd want to look at the [`FlutterSoundPlayer`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_sound/latest/player/FlutterSoundPlayer-class.html) and its [`openAudioSession`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_sound/latest/player/FlutterSoundPlayer/openAudioSession.html) method and the [`AudioDevice`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_sound_platform_interface/latest/flutter_sound_platform_interface/AudioDevice.html) enum

Answer (score 1):

Add `audio_service` package to your project and use

```
List<AudioDevice> audioDevices = (await session.getDevices()).toList();
```

to get the list of audio devices present

refer: https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session

Comment: The package name is `audio_session`, not `audio_service`.